# Update nested map

Tags: elixir

I have this map:

```
%{project: %{title: "Frank's Project"}}
```

I want to update the map to look like this:

```
%{project: %{title: "Frank's Project", subtitle: "another one"}}
```

How can I do this?

My previous attempt didn't work:

```
Map.put_new(params[:project], :subtitle, "another one")
```

returned this:

```
%{starterTopic: "garden", title: "Frank's Project"}
```

Which is not quite correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`Kernel.put_in/3`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_in/3):

```rb
iex(1)> map = %{project: %{title: "Frank's Project"}}
%{project: %{title: "Frank's Project"}}
iex(2)> map = put_in(map, [:project, :subtitle], "another one")
%{project: %{subtitle: "another one", title: "Frank's Project"}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Elixir has a convenience macro in `Kernel` (automatically imported) called [`put_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_in/2) (or there's [`put_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_in/3), which is a function alternative and probably a little easier to understand what's going on).

```rb
iex> map = %{project: %{title: "Frank's Project"}}
%{project: %{title: "Frank's Project"}}
iex> put_in(map.project[:subtitle], "another_one")
%{project: %{subtitle: "another_one", title: "Frank's Project"}}
```

Comment: `put_in/2` is a macro and `put_in/3` is a function.